# Issue with next-auth on AWS Docker Deployment

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, next-auth

I have used next-auth for Authentication in my next.js project and have deployed it on AWS server using DOcker. I am getting "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error?error=Something%20went%20wrong!%20Please%20try%20again%20later." in responce of network everytime when I try to login or register and on all the pages where I have uset nextauth.

This is my nextauth code:
[...nextauth.js]

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';

import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

import { API_BASE_URL } from '../../../utils/constants';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'credentials',
      name: 'Busfabrik',
      credentials: {
        email_id: {
          label: 'email',
          type: 'email',
        },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' }
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const payload = {
          email_id: credentials.email_id,
          password: credentials.password,
          isadmin: !!credentials.isadmin
        };

        const res = await fetch(API_BASE_URL + '/users/login', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(payload),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
        });

        const user = await res.json();
        // console.log('user', user);
        // If error and we don't have user data, return error
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error(user.exception);
        }
        // If no error and we have user data, return it
        if (res.ok && user.success) {
          return user;
        } else {
          // Return error if user data could not be retrieved
          throw new Error(user.msg);
        }
      },
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      // console.log('jwt user', user)
      if (user && user.success) {
        return {
          ...token,
          accessToken: user.payload.token,
          userData: user.payload
        };
      }

      return token;
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      // console.log('session', session);
      // console.log('session token', token);
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.user = token.userData;

      return session;
    },
  },
  theme: {
    colorScheme: 'auto', // "auto" | "dark" | "light"
    brandColor: '', // Hex color code #33FF5D
    logo: '/vercel.svg', // Absolute URL to image
  },
  // Enable debug messages in the console if you are having problems
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
});
```

Can someone suggest or have aced the same issue? If Yes, then please guide me on this. I an stuck here from a long time and not able to find the solution.